# regenerateExpiredSessionId for cookieless="UseCookies"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

How can I configure Asp.Net to use new session ID each time a new user session starts. I've read avout `regenerateExpiredSessionId` and setting it to false but that only works in `cookieless="True"`. How can I configure it to use the same behavior in `UseCookies`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use session with cookies enabled asp.net does not allocate memory for session data until a session object is created. Because of this a new session id will be generated for each page request.
In this case you can create a session instance inside Session_start event of Global.asax file.

Please refer the following link for further information,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.sessionid.aspx